# LifeRay Maven multiproject

Tags: maven, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-service-builder

I want to create project with a few comonents:

1.Portlet

2.Service to portlet

3.Liferay's hook

4.Liferay's layout

5.Project's service

6.Project's theme

all subprojects I want to build with Maven and in the first step (creating "Liferay Plugin Project") i have following problem:

[image]

There exists some good tutorial step by step ? Thanks in advance ! ! !

Comment: Did you try to create the plugin manually (with `mvn archetype:generate`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below links should be helpful to begin with:

- https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/creating-liferay-plugins-with-maven
- https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/liferay-plugin-types-to-develop-with-maven
- https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/developing-plugins-using-maven-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-02-en